Valgrind gives an error "Invalid read of size 4"
I'm reading float data in from a file and Valgrind gives the error "Invalid read of size 4". I'm a new user of Valgrind and don't understand why I get this error.
My code is:
int main() 
{
    N = 220928;
    std::vector<std::complex<float>> rxTmp(N);

    FILE *fid;
    char fn[] = "data.bin";
    fid = fopen(fn, "rb");

    std::size_t ct = fread(&rxTmp[0],4,N,fid);

    fclose(fid);  

    return 0;
}

The code compiles and executes without error but Valgrind gives the invalid read.
==41376== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==41376== Invalid read of size 4
==41376==    at 0x77E0180: fread (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==41376==    by 0x423F67: main (main.cc:77)
==41376==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

where line 77 is the fread statement.
The file size is correct; there are 220928*4 floats in the file.
Reading in any value less than N results in the same Valgrind error.
I tried changing the number of elements read to less than the number of elements in the file and still get the Valgrind error

the file size should be 220928 complexes, 2209282 floats, 2209282*4 bytes. But your file should have enough data as is. Is your file correctly open ? You did not check fid for null. I suspect the 4 bytes that fread tries to read are the 4 bytes pointed to by a null fid (the incriminated address is 0x0 as stated)

Code is incomplete without headers.  The error message doesn't match code (main.cc:77).  N is undeclared.  Why are you using fopen() and fread() in C++ code?

What OS, CPU architecture, Valgrind version, compiler and C++ standard library?

Shouldn’t you be using sizeof(complex) rather than 4?

Check errno to see why your call to fopen is failing.

Any reason not to use fstream and std::copy()? (or std::copy_n()
